# Ubuntu Font in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

How do I use the font provided by Ubuntu in LaTeX?

Eg.

[image]

Comment: Can you at least tell us the name of the font? Then there are lots of duplicates on this site for using system fonts

Comment: As @percusse says. Just install the font and then use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. Lots of questions explain how.

Comment: @cfr Well, the font is installed already, as he uses it in that editor. Subham: If you don't know the name of the font, go into the preferences of the editor (Gedit?), you can find which font is used there I'd think.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Probably. But it does no harm to point it out. (After all, the OP might want to use the font on a different system or have found a screenshot on the web.)

Comment: For users not using Ubuntu: The whole font family is available on [Ubuntu Font Family](http://font.ubuntu.com/) – or at Google Fonts http://www.google.com/fonts .

Comment: Yes, I've tried `\usepackage{fontspec}` with `xelatex` and `\setmonofont{Ubuntu}` and `\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}` but it does not give me all the unicodes in the PDF that I do get in the terminal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think it is probably Ubuntu Mono:

[image: Ubuntu Mono]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Ubuntu Mono}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to use it as the main font for the document, `fontspec` allows you to configure it for specific uses or as your 'typewriter' font.

For example, you might want Ubuntu Mono as your 'typewriter' font and Ubuntu for sans:

[image: Ubuntu and Ubuntu Mono for sans and typewriter]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Ubuntu}% Ubuntu as sans - use \sffamily or \textsf{} as normal
\setmonofont{Ubuntu Mono}% Ubuntu Mono as 'typewriter' - use \ttfamily or \texttt{}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

{\noindent\sffamily Ubuntu:

\kant[1]}

{\noindent\ttfamily Ubuntu Mono:

\kant[2]}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use Ubuntu Mono for certain elements but not set it up as the default anything, you can specify a command to switch to it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\ubuntumono{Ubuntu Mono}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

This is some text in the regular font.

{\ubuntumono This is some text in Ubuntu Mono.}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following (rather ugly) output but demonstrates the idea:

[image: Ubuntu Mono via \ubuntumono]

Answer (score 3):

You can use any system font with the `xetex` or `luatex` engines with the `fontspec` package as a nice interface.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Ubuntu}
\begin{document}
The lazy fox jumpes over the brown dog.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not the right font, though. Compare the 'i's ;).