# Ubuntu truetype fonts not found by .sty files

Tags: beamer, fontspec, linux, truetype

Based on [this accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169776/99577), the installed fonts in Ubuntu should be available to fontspec.

This is the first 20 lines of the [gemini beamer theme](https://github.com/anishathalye/gemini):

```
% Gemini theme
% https://github.com/anishathalye/gemini

% ====================
% Dependencies
% ====================

\RequirePackage{exscale}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}

% ====================
% Fonts
% ====================

\newfontfamily\Raleway[Ligatures=TeX]{Raleway}
\newfontfamily\Lato[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

Note that both Raleway and Lato appear to be installed:

```
me@s2:~/code/pcquery_poster$ fc-list|grep Raleway
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf: Raleway,Raleway ExtraBold:style=ExtraBold Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-SemiBoldItalic.ttf: Raleway,Raleway SemiBold:style=SemiBold Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-ExtraBold.ttf: Raleway,Raleway ExtraBold:style=ExtraBold,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-ExtraLightItalic.ttf: Raleway,Raleway ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-Bold.ttf: Raleway:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-MediumItalic.ttf: Raleway,Raleway Medium:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-BlackItalic.ttf: Raleway,Raleway Black:style=Black Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-Black.ttf: Raleway,Raleway Black:style=Black,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-Medium.ttf: Raleway,Raleway Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-BoldItalic.ttf: Raleway:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-ExtraLight.ttf: Raleway,Raleway ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-Light.ttf: Raleway,Raleway Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-Regular.ttf: Raleway:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-Thin.ttf: Raleway,Raleway Thin:style=Thin,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-LightItalic.ttf: Raleway,Raleway Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-ThinItalic.ttf: Raleway,Raleway Thin:style=Thin Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-Italic.ttf: Raleway:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/raleway/Raleway-SemiBold.ttf: Raleway,Raleway SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
me@s2:~/code/pcquery_poster$ fc-list|grep Lato
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Medium.ttf: Lato,Lato Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-SemiboldItalic.ttf: Lato,Lato Semibold:style=Semibold Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-LightItalic.ttf: Lato,Lato Light:style=Light Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Italic.ttf: Lato:style=Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-MediumItalic.ttf: Lato,Lato Medium:style=Medium Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Black.ttf: Lato,Lato Black:style=Black,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Light.ttf: Lato,Lato Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Regular.ttf: Lato:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-ThinItalic.ttf: Lato,Lato Thin:style=Thin Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-HairlineItalic.ttf: Lato,Lato Hairline:style=Hairline Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Thin.ttf: Lato,Lato Thin:style=Thin,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-BoldItalic.ttf: Lato:style=Bold Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Bold.ttf: Lato:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Heavy.ttf: Lato,Lato Heavy:style=Heavy,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Semibold.ttf: Lato,Lato Semibold:style=Semibold,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-HeavyItalic.ttf: Lato,Lato Heavy:style=Heavy Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-BlackItalic.ttf: Lato,Lato Black:style=Black Italic,Italic
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lato/Lato-Hairline.ttf: Lato,Lato Hairline:style=Hairline,Regular
```

However, when I try to compile my beamer poster, I get errors about latex not being able to find these fonts:

```
Package: fontspec 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2022/01/15 v2.8a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count349
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count350
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count351
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count352
\l__fontspec_tmpa_int=\count353
\l__fontspec_tmpb_int=\count354
\l__fontspec_tmpc_int=\count355
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count356
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count357
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count358
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count359
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen285
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen286
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen287
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))

./beamerthemegemini.sty:18: Package fontspec Error: The font "Raleway" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
```

Comment: You might try `luatfload-tool --cache=erase` followed by `luaotfload-tool -u` (if that does not help, it will not hurt).

Comment: Are you using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX? It is a known issue with XeLaTeX that it doesn't always find fonts by the name, and you need to use the filename instead (which means specifying all variants manually if they are stored in different files like here). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/320096/xelatex-fontspec-cannot-find-fonts for more information.

Comment: @Marijn THANK YOU -- I was indeed using XeLaTeX and just tried switching to LuaLaTeX in my latexmk and it's working as expected now!