Unable to update font map file and use TTF in LaTeX document
I would like to use Ubuntu's Mono font as a fixed width font in my LaTeX document. Please find below the steps I accomplished:

Run autoinst on my *.ttf files
Copied generated files into my local LaTeX distribution. I use TeX-Live installed via MacPorts. My distribution lives under /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/.
Refreshed LaTeX package tree with

sudo mktexlsr
sudo texhash


Configured font maps with

sudo updmap -sys --enable Map *.map


Used Ubuntu's Mono font name from TFM file generated under

/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/UbuntuMono/

I need help to ensure I do steps 4 and 5 correctly. When I run step 4 in the directory where UbuntuMono.map resides (/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/map/dvips/UbuntuMono/) I obtain the following output:
sudo updmap -sys --enable Map *.map
Password:
updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /Users/mabalenk) to root's actual home (/var/root).
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /opt/local/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /opt/local/var/db/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /opt/local/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
/opt/local/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: updating ls-R files

It seems the map files are not being updated correctly.
Finally, I'm not certain which font name should I use in my LaTeX document. There are plenty under /opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/tfm/lcdftools/UbuntuMono:
UbuntuMono-Regular-sup-ly1--base.tfm  UbuntuMono-Regular-sup-t1--base.tfm   UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-ly1.tfm       UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-t1.tfm
UbuntuMono-Regular-sup-ly1.tfm        UbuntuMono-Regular-sup-t1.tfm         UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-ot1.tfm       UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-ts1--base.tfm
UbuntuMono-Regular-sup-ot1.tfm        UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-ly1--base.tfm  UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-t1--base.tfm  UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-ts1.tfm

I include the Mono font into my LaTeX document as
% Set Ubuntu Mono font as default for monospace cathegory
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{UbuntuMono-Regular}

The outcome of running pdflatex on my code results in a warning and Ubuntu's Mono not being used:
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/UbuntuMono-Regular/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 127.

Please find below contents of the UbuntuMono.map file:
% Automatically maintained by otftotfm or other programs. Do not edit.

UbuntuMono-Bold-tlf-ot1 UbuntuMono-Bold "AutoEnc_owiucwjzslm2tzg7kwlyu23eka ReEncodeFont" <[a_owiucw.enc <UbuntuMono-B.ttf
UbuntuMono-Bold-tlf-ly1--base UbuntuMono-Bold "AutoEnc_fmzw26ifncvzbymm2smg6y63he ReEncodeFont" <[a_fmzw26.enc <UbuntuMono-B.ttf
UbuntuMono-Bold-tlf-t1--base UbuntuMono-Bold "AutoEnc_azsqwgpibjk6zr6c2h3lkaqfnh ReEncodeFont" <[a_azsqwg.enc <UbuntuMono-B.ttf
UbuntuMono-Bold-tlf-ts1--base UbuntuMono-Bold "AutoEnc_qrv2wbxrln7jxa4lmlstqcarqa ReEncodeFont" <[a_qrv2wb.enc <UbuntuMono-B.ttf
UbuntuMono-Bold-sup-ot1 UbuntuMono-Bold "AutoEnc_dd7vacd4hpl2wnbsvdcq4vyfua ReEncodeFont" <[a_dd7vac.enc <UbuntuMono-B.ttf
UbuntuMono-Bold-sup-ly1--base UbuntuMono-Bold "AutoEnc_2j46ldbfhj6nwj4apc76jkzuwb ReEncodeFont" <[a_2j46ld.enc <UbuntuMono-B.ttf
UbuntuMono-Bold-sup-t1--base UbuntuMono-Bold "AutoEnc_e2s627mog5uo6w334uxzlkbxfa ReEncodeFont" <[a_e2s627.enc <UbuntuMono-B.ttf
UbuntuMono-BoldItalic-tlf-ot1 UbuntuMono-BoldItalic "AutoEnc_owiucwjzslm2tzg7kwlyu23eka ReEncodeFont" <[a_owiucw.enc <UbuntuMono-BI.ttf
UbuntuMono-BoldItalic-tlf-ly1--base UbuntuMono-BoldItalic "AutoEnc_fmzw26ifncvzbymm2smg6y63he ReEncodeFont" <[a_fmzw26.enc <UbuntuMono-BI.ttf
UbuntuMono-BoldItalic-tlf-t1--base UbuntuMono-BoldItalic "AutoEnc_azsqwgpibjk6zr6c2h3lkaqfnh ReEncodeFont" <[a_azsqwg.enc <UbuntuMono-BI.ttf
UbuntuMono-BoldItalic-tlf-ts1--base UbuntuMono-BoldItalic "AutoEnc_qrv2wbxrln7jxa4lmlstqcarqa ReEncodeFont" <[a_qrv2wb.enc <UbuntuMono-BI.ttf
UbuntuMono-BoldItalic-sup-ot1 UbuntuMono-BoldItalic "AutoEnc_dd7vacd4hpl2wnbsvdcq4vyfua ReEncodeFont" <[a_dd7vac.enc <UbuntuMono-BI.ttf
UbuntuMono-BoldItalic-sup-ly1--base UbuntuMono-BoldItalic "AutoEnc_2j46ldbfhj6nwj4apc76jkzuwb ReEncodeFont" <[a_2j46ld.enc <UbuntuMono-BI.ttf
UbuntuMono-BoldItalic-sup-t1--base UbuntuMono-BoldItalic "AutoEnc_e2s627mog5uo6w334uxzlkbxfa ReEncodeFont" <[a_e2s627.enc <UbuntuMono-BI.ttf
UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-ot1 UbuntuMono-Regular "AutoEnc_owiucwjzslm2tzg7kwlyu23eka ReEncodeFont" <[a_owiucw.enc <UbuntuMono-R.ttf
UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-ly1--base UbuntuMono-Regular "AutoEnc_fmzw26ifncvzbymm2smg6y63he ReEncodeFont" <[a_fmzw26.enc <UbuntuMono-R.ttf
UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-t1--base UbuntuMono-Regular "AutoEnc_azsqwgpibjk6zr6c2h3lkaqfnh ReEncodeFont" <[a_azsqwg.enc <UbuntuMono-R.ttf
UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-ts1--base UbuntuMono-Regular "AutoEnc_qrv2wbxrln7jxa4lmlstqcarqa ReEncodeFont" <[a_qrv2wb.enc <UbuntuMono-R.ttf
UbuntuMono-Regular-sup-ot1 UbuntuMono-Regular "AutoEnc_dd7vacd4hpl2wnbsvdcq4vyfua ReEncodeFont" <[a_dd7vac.enc <UbuntuMono-R.ttf
UbuntuMono-Regular-sup-ly1--base UbuntuMono-Regular "AutoEnc_2j46ldbfhj6nwj4apc76jkzuwb ReEncodeFont" <[a_2j46ld.enc <UbuntuMono-R.ttf
UbuntuMono-Regular-sup-t1--base UbuntuMono-Regular "AutoEnc_e2s627mog5uo6w334uxzlkbxfa ReEncodeFont" <[a_e2s627.enc <UbuntuMono-R.ttf
UbuntuMono-Italic-tlf-ot1 UbuntuMono-Italic "AutoEnc_owiucwjzslm2tzg7kwlyu23eka ReEncodeFont" <[a_owiucw.enc <UbuntuMono-RI.ttf
UbuntuMono-Italic-tlf-ly1--base UbuntuMono-Italic "AutoEnc_fmzw26ifncvzbymm2smg6y63he ReEncodeFont" <[a_fmzw26.enc <UbuntuMono-RI.ttf
UbuntuMono-Italic-tlf-t1--base UbuntuMono-Italic "AutoEnc_azsqwgpibjk6zr6c2h3lkaqfnh ReEncodeFont" <[a_azsqwg.enc <UbuntuMono-RI.ttf
UbuntuMono-Italic-tlf-ts1--base UbuntuMono-Italic "AutoEnc_qrv2wbxrln7jxa4lmlstqcarqa ReEncodeFont" <[a_qrv2wb.enc <UbuntuMono-RI.ttf
UbuntuMono-Italic-sup-ot1 UbuntuMono-Italic "AutoEnc_dd7vacd4hpl2wnbsvdcq4vyfua ReEncodeFont" <[a_dd7vac.enc <UbuntuMono-RI.ttf
UbuntuMono-Italic-sup-ly1--base UbuntuMono-Italic "AutoEnc_2j46ldbfhj6nwj4apc76jkzuwb ReEncodeFont" <[a_2j46ld.enc <UbuntuMono-RI.ttf
UbuntuMono-Italic-sup-t1--base UbuntuMono-Italic "AutoEnc_e2s627mog5uo6w334uxzlkbxfa ReEncodeFont" <[a_e2s627.enc <UbuntuMono-RI.ttf

Ubuntu's Mono *.fd files may be found under
/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/UbuntuMono

These are
LY1UbuntuMono-Sup.fd  LY1UbuntuMono-TLF.fd  OT1UbuntuMono-Sup.fd  OT1UbuntuMono-TLF.fd  T1UbuntuMono-Sup.fd  T1UbuntuMono-TLF.fd  TS1UbuntuMono-TLF.fd

I'm using the fontenc package and setting Ubuntu's Mono as a default fixed width font with:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{UbuntuMono-TLF}

I can see UbuntuMono in the list of available font maps:
updmap -sys --listavailablemaps | grep UbuntuMono
93:Map  UbuntuMono.map  enabled /Users/mabalenk/.texlive2024/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg

Please find my minimal example below:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{UbuntuMono-TLF}

\begin{document}

\texttt{Hello, world!}

\end{document}

The output of the pdfTeX follows:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024/MacPorts 2024.70613_0) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./mini.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file mini.aux.
(/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/UbuntuMono/T1UbuntuMono-TLF.fd)
[1{/opt/local/var/db/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/opt/local/share
/texmf-texlive/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}] (./mini.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-t1--base
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-t1--base.
mktexpk: perhaps UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-t1--base is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file UbuntuMono-Regular-tlf-t1--base): Font UbuntuMono
-Regular-tlf-t1--base at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


What's in the .map files? Do you have .fd files and, if so, where? Do you have to use pdfTeX or is LuaTeX (or XeTeX) an option?

I updated my question with the contents of the *.map file and location of the *.fd files. I don't have to use pdfTeX, but I would prefer to.

For XeTeX or LuaTeX, see my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169772/ubuntu-font-in-latex/169776#169776.

Try \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and then \renewcommand{\ttdefault}{UbuntuMono-TLF}.

^ For pdfTeX. (Presumably that's obvious since you know enough to have got this far.)

The output from updmap is expected if you've already installed the map file once. Actually, I tend not to do this for truetype fonts at all, unless I'm converting them to type1. But that's not relevant here. You can check whether the map is installed using e.g. updmap --listavailablemaps | grep UbuntuMono.
